# If $f(x)$ is concave, is $f(\lambda x) \le \lambda f(x)$ for $\lambda > 1$?

Tags: analysis

If $f(x)$ is concave, is $f(\lambda x) \le \lambda f(x)$ for $\lambda > 1$ ?

A have a strong feeling that this should be the case. 
However, using the definition of concavity:

$f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y) \ge \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha) f(y)$

or the criterion $f''(x) < 0)$

did not yet prove useful in showing the desired result.

Am I confusing things here, or do I simply fail to see the obvious? Thanks!

Comment: Consider $f(x) = \log x - 1$. For that, we have $f(2\cdot 1) = \log 2 - 1 > - 2 = 2(\log 1 - 1)$.

Comment: If $f$ is cocanve and $f(0)=0$ then you can prove that $f(\lambda x)\leq\lambda f(x)$ for $\lambda>1$.

Comment: If it were true for every $f$ concave, it would also be true for every $f+c$. Then the limit $c\to-\infty$ would put you in trouble.

Comment: @Tomás, how can you prove it in that case?

Comment: Take $\lambda>1$, $y=0$ and $x=\lambda z$.

Comment: You mean for some $z > 0$? I'm sorry, but I still don't see how to show that the inequality holds.